# Angular Highchart - Set Timezone

Tags: angular, highcharts

I´m trying to set timezone in [Angular Highchart](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-angular-wrapper/).

Code looks like

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
              time: {
                useUTC: false,
                timezone: "America/Lima"
              }
            });
```

If i return full config.

```
 chart: {styledMode: false, borderRadius: 0, colorCount: 10, defaultSeriesType: "line", ignoreHiddenSeries: true, …}
    colors: (10) ["#7cb5ec", "#434348", "#90ed7d", "#f7a35c", "#8085e9", "#f15c80", "#e4d354", "#2b908f", "#f45b5b", "#91e8e1"]
    credits: {enabled: false, href: "https://www.highcharts.com?credits", position: {…}, style: {…}, text: "Highcharts.com"}
    exporting: {type: "image/png", url: "https://export.highcharts.com/", printMaxWidth: 780, scale: 2, buttons: {…}, …}
    global: {}
    labels: {style: {…}}
    lang: {loading: "Cargando...", months: Array(12), shortMonths: Array(12), weekdays: Array(7), decimalPoint: ",", …}
    legend: {enabled: true, align: "center", alignColumns: true, layout: "horizontal", labelFormatter: ƒ, …}
    loading: {labelStyle: {…}, style: {…}}
    navigation: {buttonOptions: {…}, menuStyle: {…}, menuItemStyle: {…}, menuItemHoverStyle: {…}}
    navigator: {height: 40, margin: 25, maskInside: true, handles: {…}, maskFill: "rgba(102,133,194,0.3)", …}
    noData: {position: {…}, style: {…}}
    plotOptions: {line: {…}, area: {…}, spline: {…}, areaspline: {…}, column: {…}, …}
    rangeSelector: {verticalAlign: "top", buttonTheme: {…}, floating: false, x: 0, y: 0, …}
    scrollbar: {height: 14, barBorderRadius: 0, buttonBorderRadius: 0, liveRedraw: undefined, margin: 10, …}
    subtitle: {text: "", align: "center", widthAdjust: -44}
    symbols: (5) ["circle", "diamond", "square", "triangle", "triangle-down"]
    time: //HERE
    timezone: "America/Lima"
    useUTC: false
    __proto__: Object
    title: {text: "Chart title", align: "center", margin: 15, widthAdjust: -44}
    tooltip: {enabled: true, animation: true, borderRadius: 3, dateTimeLabelFormats: {…}, footerFormat: "", …}
    xAxis: {type: "datetime", ordinal: false, crosshair: {…}}
    __proto__: Object
```

So apparently should works, but it doesn´t. Highchart take wrong timezone, take timezone of current location.

So the question is:What is the right way to set timezone in angular highchart?

**UPDATE**

Full code

```
import  *  as  moment  from  "moment";

import  *  as  moment_timezone  from  "moment-timezone";

Highcharts  =  Highcharts;

Highcharts.setOptions({

     time: {

          timezone:  "America/Lima"

     }
})
```

Return

> z.tz is not a function

**UPDATE 2**

The problem is imports. I can´t take the timezone as we can see  [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/), so i can´t set this option properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts needs `moment.js` to be loaded globally on the `window` object.

The **workaround** for this issue. In the main.ts file add these lines:

```
import * as moment_timezone from "moment-timezone";
(window as any).moment = moment_timezone;
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-5toq0

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you haven't included all relevant `momemt.js` files? In case Highcharts is not able to calculate the correct time zone it will still show the report but just without applying the time offset.

These files (or any newer version) should be included:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Then set your time zone using `Highcharts.setOptions()`:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    time: {
        timezone: "America/Lima"
    }
});
```

The parameter `UTC: false` is redundant as soon as you manually set the time zone. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/ezy76uvb/6/) with your time zone.

P.S. and don't forget that missing double quote after "Lima".

**Update**

Someone in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929597/highchart-z-tz-is-not-a-function) mentioned that you need to manually include moment.js and moment-timezone.js in `<script>` tags. The question author also encountered

> z.tz is not a function

so this might be a solution.

Comment: I use TS files so i use imports like this import * as moment from "moment";
import * as moment_timezone from "moment-timezone"; but return z.tz is not a function.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre could it be you need to provide an alias to the import so the function becomes available? Like `import * as z from "moment-timezone";`

Comment: Like this import * as moment from "moment";
import * as moment_timezone from "moment-timezone";
import * as moment_data from 'moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-1970-2030.min' ?

Comment: No, change the last import to `import * as z from "moment-moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-1970-2030.min`

Comment: import * as moment from "moment";
import * as moment_timezone from "moment-timezone";
import * as z from "moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-1970-2030.min"  Highcharts.setOptions({
              time: {
                timezone:"America/Lima"
            
                } same error

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre just realized the post I referred to was written by you. What happens if you append the file suffix in the import: `import * as z from "moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-1970-2030.min.js"`?

Comment: Continue return z.tz is not a function

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre it seems that moment makes its functions available as a local variable that can't be accessed later-on as the variable is no longer accessible. [This Highcharts Github issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8661) describes the problem and might contain a solution.